# How to show each type of content-types just one time?

Tags: views, nodes

I have news content type and it has title, body, image and type. The type is a **list(text)** and have these values:

1. sport
2. Economy
3. Health
4. ...

And now I need to have these types in a **view (block)**. in view module the field is **type** *(means the news type)* I just want each of them shows one time not showing by each published news content.

**For example**: in that block that I made I have 3 sport news and 2 health news and one Economy!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question. Do you want to use the Type of the node as header for a collection of nodes?
So:

**Sport**
Node 1
Node 2
Node 3

**Health**
Node 4
Node 5

**Economy**
Node 6

What I would do is use the Views field view module. First make a view for all three groups, so you have three views one for Sport, one for Health and one of Economy. Give them all a header with the Type name. Then add all these views to one view with this module.

Comment: Another option is to use Attachments in Views. So make one view (block or page) for one Type for example Sport. And add two attachments one for Health and one for Economy. Add the attachments to the Block or Page and your done.